# Creating Oracle Sequence Trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, sequence

I'm trying create seuqunce trigger but error occurs when I executing the trigger create sql in SQL Developer. I don't understand, actually everything looks fine. I share the details below, please help me, thanks.

My trigger sql:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TRIGGER1" BEFORE INSERT ON ACCOUNTS
FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (new."ID" IS NULL) 
BEGIN
  SELECT ACCOUNTS_SEQ.NEXTVAL 
  INTO :new."ID" 
  FROM dual;
END;
/
```

And error description:

```
Error starting at line : 5 in command -
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TRIGGER1" BEFORE INSERT ON ACCOUNTS
FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (new."ID" IS NULL) 
BEGIN
  SELECT ACCOUNTS_SEQ.NEXTVAL 
  INTO :new."ID" 
  FROM dual
Error report -
SQL Command: trıgger "TRIGGER1"
Failed: Warning: completed with warning

Error starting at line : 12 in command -
END
Error report -
Unknown Command
```

Comment: Get rid off those double quotes and recompile.

Comment: `ID` needs to be the actual field in the `ACCOUNTS` table, too.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1
BEFORE INSERT ON ACCOUNTS
FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (new.ID IS NULL)
BEGIN
  :new.ID := ACCOUNTS_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
END;
/
```

Your sequence should look like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ACCOUNTS_SEQ 
  START WITH 1 
  INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, trigger was created bu I can't compile it. Error(8,11): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ;

Comment: Now trigger sql looks like: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1
BEFORE INSERT ON ACCOUNTS
FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (new.ID IS NULL) 
BEGIN
  SELECT ACCOUNTS_SEQ.NEXTVAL 
  INTO :new.ID
  FROM dual

Comment: Make sure you are using `/` after the block.

Comment: I'm sure but same result

Comment: and also after `from dual` you need to add `END;`

Comment: Do you have a blank line between the line "   FROM dual;" and the line "END;" ? It looks like your SQL Developer thinks the CREATE statement ends after "dual;". Might be SQL Developer settings or perhaps an old version of SQL Developer? Maybe you should try to create the trigger in SQL*Plus to see if it is your syntax that fails or it is some reason SQL Developer chops your statement prematurely.

Comment: actually I did but I do not know why SQL Developer cutting my sql command, I run the exact same your command

Comment: Yes, problem in SQL Developer Program, SQL Plus run correctly.

Comment: I ran everything in SQL Developer, as above, just fine, except my sequence is a little difference since we have an existing table and it needs to increment off the existing records.  I did have to make sure I included the last `/`, but after doing so, ran fine. I have Version 3.2.20.10.

Comment: As of at least 12c, there is no need for any options on the `CREATE SEQUENCE <seqname>` statement. A sequence is by default ascending, therefore by default minval is 1, therefore by default starts with 1, and by default increments by 1.

Comment: Triggers, indexes, constraints, and sequences are in different namespaces, so you can name all of them PK_mytablename to make the association between them obvious.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1
BEFORE INSERT ON ACCOUNTS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :new.ID IS NULL THEN 
SELECT ACCOUNTS_SEQ.NEXTVAL 
INTO :new.ID
FROM dual;
END IF;
END;
```