# Oracle SQL - How can I write an insert statement that is conditional and looped?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, conditional-statements, liquibase

Context:
I have two tables: markettypewagerlimitgroups (mtwlg) and stakedistributionindicators (sdi). When a mtwlg is created, 2 rows are created in the sdi table which are linked to the mtwlg - each row with the same values bar 2, the id and another field (let's call it column X) which must contain a 0 for one row and 1 for the other.
There was a bug present in our codebase which prevented this happening automatically, so any mtwlg's created during the time that bug was present do not have the related sdi's, causing NPE's in various places.

To fix this, a patch needs to be written to loop through the mtwlg table and for each ID, search the sdi table for the 2 related rows. If the rows are present, do nothing; if there is only 1 row, check if F is a 0 or a 1, and insert a row with the other value; if neither row is present, insert them both. This needs to be done for every mtwlg, and a unique ID needs to be inserted too.

Pseudocode:

```
For each market type wager limit group ID
    Check if there are 2 rows with that id in the stake distributions table, 1 where column X = 0 and one where column X = 1
    if none
        create 2 rows in the stake distributions table with unique id's; 1 for each X value
    if one
        create the missing row in the stake distributions table with a unique id
    if 2
        do nothing
```

If it helps at all - the patch will be applied using liquibase.

Anyone with any advice or thoughts as to if and how this will be possible to write in SQL/a liquibase patch?

Thanks in advance, let me know of any other information you need.

EDIT:

I've actually just been advised to do this using PL/SQL, do you have any thoughts/suggestions in regards to this?
Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oooooh, an excellent job for [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm).

Here's your pseudo code again:

```
For each market type wager limit group ID
    Check if there are 2 rows with that id in the stake distributions table,
        1 where column X = 0 and one where column X = 1
    if none
        create 2 rows in the stake distributions table with unique id's; 
        1 for each X value
    if one
        create the missing row in the stake distributions table with a unique id
    if 2
        do nothing
```

Here's the `MERGE` variant (still pseudo-code'ish as I don't know how your data really looks):

```sql
MERGE INTO stake_distributions d
USING (
  SELECT limit_group_id, 0 AS x
  FROM market_type_wagers
  UNION ALL
  SELECT limit_group_id, 1 AS x
  FROM market_type_wagers
) t
ON (
  d.limit_group_id = t.limit_group_id AND d.x = t.x
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (d.limit_group_id, d.x)
VALUES (t.limit_group_id, t.x);
```

No loops, no PL/SQL, no conditional statements, just plain beautiful SQL.

Nice alternative suggested by [Boneist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30233998/521799) in the comments uses a `CROSS JOIN` rather than `UNION ALL` in the `USING` clause, which is *likely* to perform better (unverified):

```sql
MERGE INTO stake_distributions d
USING (
  SELECT w.limit_group_id, x.x
  FROM market_type_wagers w
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 AS x FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS x FROM DUAL
  ) x
) t
ON (
  d.limit_group_id = t.limit_group_id AND d.x = t.x
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (d.limit_group_id, d.x)
VALUES (t.limit_group_id, t.x);
```

Comment: *"could I simply use MAX(d.id)+1"* NO! Never do that :-) There are tons of reasons why this can go wrong (mostly race conditions). Ideally, you'll use a sequence, e.g. as suggested by [user boneist here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30233998/521799). Either explicitly or [via a trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660307/creating-oracle-sequence-trigger)

Comment: to speed up performance, you could replace that union all with a cross join on a dummy 2-row table/subquery

Comment: @Boneist: Absolutely! Thanks for the hint

Comment: I've just been recommended by a colleague to do this using PL/SQL, which should trivialise this issue. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @James: I don't see the advantage of using PL/SQL here. Although, you most certainly can...

Comment: @James There is no reason to use PL/SQL when the same could be achieved in pure SQL.

Comment: I'd be curious to know what your colleague meant by suggesting you do it in PL/SQL. You can certainly plug the INSERT / MERGE statement into PL/SQL, but if they meant do a cursor-for-loop, then I would say that far from trivialising the issue, it makes it much more complicated and also slower. Think of it like this: you have 200 bricks at the bottom of your drive which you want to use to build a wall at the top of your drive. Do you a) move one brick at a time, making 200 round trips, or b) put all the bricks into a wheelbarrow and use that to move them, making 1 round trip?

Answer (score 2):

Answer: you don't. There is absolutely no need to loop through anything - you can do it in a single insert. All you need to do is identify the rows that are missing, and then you just need to add them in.

Here is an example:

```
drop table t1;
drop table t2;
drop sequence t2_seq;

create table t1 (cola number,
                 colb number,
                 colc number);

create table t2 (id number,
                 cola number,
                 colb number,
                 colc number,
                 colx number);

create sequence t2_seq
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  MAXVALUE 99999999
  MINVALUE 1
  NOCYCLE
  CACHE 20
  NOORDER;

insert into t1 values (1, 10, 100);
insert into t2 values (t2_seq.nextval, 1, 10, 100, 0);
insert into t2 values (t2_seq.nextval, 1, 10, 100, 1);

insert into t1 values (2, 20, 200);
insert into t2 values (t2_seq.nextval, 2, 20, 200, 0);

insert into t1 values (3, 30, 300);
insert into t2 values (t2_seq.nextval, 3, 30, 300, 1);

insert into t1 values (4, 40, 400);

commit;

insert into t2 (id, cola, colb, colc, colx)
with dummy as (select 1 id from dual union all
               select 0 id from dual)
select t2_seq.nextval,
       t1.cola,
       t1.colb,
       t1.colc,
       d.id
from   t1
       cross join dummy d
       left outer join t2 on (t2.cola = t1.cola and d.id = t2.colx)
where  t2.id is null;

commit;

select * from t2
order by t2.cola;

        ID       COLA       COLB       COLC       COLX
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1         10        100          0
         2          1         10        100          1
         3          2         20        200          0
         5          2         20        200          1
         7          3         30        300          0
         4          3         30        300          1
         6          4         40        400          0
         8          4         40        400          1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the processing logic is too gnarly to be encapsulated in a single SQL statement, you may need to resort to cursor for loops and row types - basically allows you to do things like the following:

```
DECLARE

    r_mtwlg markettypewagerlimitgroups%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

    FOR r_mtwlg IN (
        SELECT mtwlg.*
        FROM markettypewagerlimitgroups mtwlg
    )
    LOOP
        -- do stuff here
        -- refer to elements of the current row like this
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r_mtwlg.id);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

You can obviously nest another loop inside this one that hits the `stakedistributionindicators` table, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you. You could also left join to `stakedistributionindicators` a couple of times in this first cursor so that you only return rows that don't already have an x=1 and x=0, again you can probably work that bit out for yourself.

Comment: How are id's currently generated under normal usage? Most Oracle database pre version 12 would use a sequence for this purpose, if your system is using a sequence you can just use the same one.

Comment: Also, assuming that the `stakedistributionindicators` table has a primary key based on the `id`, then rather than worrying about the conditional part of your question you could just always attempt the insert for both values of `x` but catch the primary key violation exception and do nothing. This way you'd be guaranteed to always get your two rows and the logic would be more simpler.

Comment: Why suggest cursor for loops (aka row-by-row, aka slow-by-slow) when you can easily do this in a single SQL statement? Performance will be much slower if you do it this way.

Comment: Because it's a valid option? Because maybe if the logic was a little more complicated it couldn't be done in a single SQL statement? I'm guessing the downvote was from you also, thanks.

Comment: You should only rely on cursor for loops if you absolutely can't do the logic in a single sql statement. It's the equivalent of the OP asking  "I've got a bath full of water, a tablespoon and a jug; which should I use to get the water out of the bath" and you replying "Use the jug." It's certainly a valid answer, but most people would plump for "Remove the plug!" as that'll be faster and easier!

Comment: Also, your suggestion of nesting the loops? Noooooo! {head in hands} By suggesting that, you're suggesting the OP effectively reinvents joins. Why bother circumventing all the code that Oracle put in the optimiser to allow SQL to decide the best type of join to use? If you absolutely have to use cursor-for-loops (and sometimes it's inescapable), at least encapsulate all the logic into a single sql statement and then loop through that!

Answer (score 0):

If you would rather write your logic in Java vs. PL/SQL, Liquibase allows you to create [custom changes](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/custom_change.html). The custom change points to a Java class you write that can do whatever logic you need. A simple example can be found [here](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/test/java/liquibase/change/custom/ExampleCustomSqlChange.java)