# Oracle Sequence or Select MAX() In an Auto Incrementing field?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We have several tables that we need to add an auto incrementing trigger(along some other fail safes)

For us, the easiest would be to use a common procedure for all tables, that uses Select MAX() to get the next incrementing value.

Or develop a somewhat complex loop to create a sequence and custom trigger for each table.

We would like to go for the easiest way, but I'm not sure if it's going to take much more processing than using a sequence, how considerable this difference would be and how to even calculate it.

Basically, how slower is `Select MAX(my_field)` compared to `my_sequence.nextval()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should use a sequence because they are so much faster than selecting from the table.

The problem with select max() from a table is that if you have more than one session at a time doing this they could both get the same max value and then add one to it and both use the same supposedly unique value. I can't really think of a reason that you would want to do select max() to get the next value.

Sequences are fast and you are guaranteed not to use the same value in multiple sessions.

Bobby

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to create a sequential id in Oracle before Oracle 12C, then use a sequence and a trigger. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660307/creating-oracle-sequence-trigger) is an example of code. It is not that hard. It is more efficient than the `MAX()` calculation.  And it does not have race conditions.

In Oracle 12C, use a `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` column. No need for a trigger at all.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tag as 11g, I'm fully aware of this new feature in 12C ^^