# Using Sequence for inserting

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to insert a new row in my table.
There I want to put the ID with the help of `seq_name.nextval`.
So how to know the sequence name for that particular table?

Comment: There is no association between sequences and tables. I may create a table `TAB1` and use a sequence `tab1_seq`, `seq_tab1`, `sequence_for_tab1`, ...

Comment: You will have to look in existing code that inserts into the table and see which sequence it uses. Or, upgrade to Oracle 12c and start using identity columns like everyone else.

Comment: In Oracle versions before 12c the only way to achieve this is by using a custom trigger : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25660884/3930237

Comment: @Aleksej how to know what is the seq we have to use--> tab1_seq, seq_tab1,sequence_for_tab1? and how to check the existing sequence in oracle>

Comment: I created a new sequence to use as below:                                                     
CREATE SEQUENCE "Kt_seq"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 100 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;                                                       Then I tried to use it for insertion but It throws error as "SQL Error: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
"  even I created synonym for the sequence Kt_seq. How should I use it for insertion?

Comment: Ther is no sequence to use. You may write 10 different insert statements and use 10 different sequences, Oracle can not restrict this. Pay attention to the double quotes when you create an object... "Kt_seq" is different from kt_seq, KT_SEQ, ...

Comment: Yes, I created like "Kt_seq" but there is only one sequence in table(all_sequences) as Kt_seq.But I am not able to use it for insertion.                                                        insert into kt1_test values(Kt_seq.nextval,'Roy','C1','8',70000);      Getting same error as SQL Error: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
''

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestion.I tried again from scratch as below and It worked                
(1). CREATE SEQUENCE kt1_test_seq  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 100 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;       (2). CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM kt1_test_seq for gem_app.kt1_test_seq;    (3). grant all on kt1_test to gem_app;                                                               (4). grant all on gem_app.kt1_test_seq to gem_app;                                       (5). insert into kt1_test values(kt1_test_seq.nextval,'Roy','C1','8',70000);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a sequence to generate IDs, you create it normally in the schema where the table is.

As user application user `GEM_APP`:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (id NUMBER, col1 ...);
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq;
```

The application user itself (and f.i. it's stored procedures) can use the sequence directly:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, col1) VALUES (my_seq.nextval, 'bla');
```

However, other users need the correct privileges. Usually, you grant select rights on the sequence to the same users or roles you grant insert rights on the table:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON my_table TO user_xy;
GRANT SELECT ON my_seq TO user_xy;
```

Then the other user can insert data into the table, but must qualify the schema:

```
INSERT INTO gem_app.my_table(id, col1) VALUES (gem_app.my_seq.nextval, 'bla');
```

You can create aliases to hide the schemas, some people like them, some not, but I would definitely not recommend to use **PUBLIC** synonyms as they are hard to control and create all kind of namespace clashes.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, this helps.

Comment: This is clear now,But earlier I was trying to access table (Other scenario) with other user, but it didn't work without synonym.Is it necessary to make the synonym or is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: Silly me, I forgot the `SELECT` privilege on the table. `GRANT INSERT on my_table` allows only to `INSERT`, but not to see the table. In normal life, it's always the combination of 'GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON my_table', but I wanted to keep the answer short and clear.

Comment: No , you were absolutely right , my question is now with the different scenario " I was trying to access table (Other scenario) with other user, but it didn't work without synonym.Is it necessary to make the synonym or is there any other way to do the same?"

Comment: Synonyms are not necessary. You can always specify the table or sequence etc with the schema name (gem_app.my_table). If the other user cannot select from the table, the privilege is missing. (Or the other user is looking at the wrong place, for instance the dictionary view ALL_TABLES instead of USER_TABLES, or in SQL Developer the folder 'Other Users' etc.

Comment: I tried without synonym but it is not working.My current schema is gem_app and  I want to access the table kt_test from the gm_user schema.                                                              GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON kt_test TO gm_user;                                                      ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = gm_user;                                             select * from kt_test;         Error : ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: You need to connect as `GM_USER` and qualify the schema name `SELECT * FROM gm_app.kt_test;`

Comment: You can use `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = gem_app` once you are connected as user GM_USER. Some people at work like that, I find it rather confusing and limiting.

Comment: Bit confusing,I connected with gem_app user only.There I want to select table with schema gm_user. It worked when I used synonyms.But only giving privileges to gm_user schema , it didn't work.

Comment: So, gm_user owns the table and the sequence, and the user gem_app wants to access them?

Comment: gem_app own the table,I gave permission to gm_user on kt_test but the user is not able to access the table.

Comment: OK. When you say "the user is not able to access the table", how do you connect to the database? You said earlier "I connected with gem_app user only"?

Comment: Yes I connected with gem_app user. Then I gave permission to schema gm_user , then alter the session to schema gm_user. Now I want to access table with gm_user schema.

Comment: Thanks for verifying that. The error is the 'alter session' statement. That leaves you still connected as user gem_app. You can verify with `SELECT user FROM dual;`. Access privileges are checked based on this value. You need to disconnect from the database and connect as user gm_user.

Comment: Thanks for help, but If I am working with a huge data, so synonyms is helpful or not?

Comment: If huge=data volume, then synonyms don't help as they are not faster. If huge=number of tables, then the number of synonyms is also huge. I use them personally very sparingly, as they are another level of indirection, where you need to look up what exactly the original is.

Comment: Thanks,In my application there is huge number of tables and synonyms are in use from a long time.