# Insert next value of sequence using cx_Oracle Cursor.executemany()

Tags: python, oracle, insert, sequence, cx-oracle

I am trying to use the cx_oracle library in python to insert rows, where one of the column values is the next value in a sequence called an_aj_s .

I have created a function to do this called insert_into_columns and the call to this function looks like this:

```
self.insert_into_columns('AN_JOB',
                         ('AJ_ID','AJ_JOBNAME', 'AJ_DESCRIPTION', 'AJ_CD_JOB_TYPE', 'AJ_CD_DATABASE','AJ_CD_JOB_STATUS', 'AJ_USR_ID', 'AJ_CREATE_DATE', 'AJ_EQUIP_COMPS_FLAG'),
                         [ ('an_aj_s.nextval', 'QlikManual_3', 'First Manually entered Test Job', 2, 0, 1  ,6 , dt.today().date(),  1)])
```

where the arguments are:
`insert_into_columns({Table Name}, {Columns to insert}, {row of values to insert}`)

When I call the function I get an error invalid number:
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01722: invalid number

I am sure that the problem is the sequence because if I replace the sequence with a number the insert is successful. Can anyone tell me how I can call my sequence when inserting rows into the table?

I have tried setting the input sizes with cur.setinputsizes() but it did not seem to work.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The SQL statement that my function generates looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO AN_JOB (AJ_ID,AJ_JOBNAME,AJ_DESCRIPTION,AJ_CD_JOB_TYPE,AJ_CD_DATABASE,AJ_CD_JOB_STATUS,AJ_USR_ID,AJ_CREATE_DATE,AJ_EQUIP_COMPS_FLAG) VALUES ( :1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9 )
```

And actual python function to generate the statement looks like this like this:

```
 def insert_into_columns(self, table_name, columns, rows):
    sql = "INSERT INTO {table_name} ({column_names}) VALUES ({column_args} )"
    args_str = ''
    col_str  = ''
    for col_id in range(1, len(columns) + 1):
        args_str += ' :' + str(col_id)
        col_str += columns[col_id - 1]
        if col_id < len(columns):
            args_str += ','
            col_str += ','

    sql = sql.format(table_name=table_name, column_names =col_str,  column_args=args_str)
    print('Inserting rows into specified columns...')
    print(sql)

    with self.conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.executemany(sql, rows)
        self.conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SQL statement, you're passing all the values as bind variables. Which is normally great! But bind variables are not *interpreted* by the SQL engine. So for the `AJ_ID` column, you're not calling sequence pseudocolumn `an_aj_s.nextval` like you want to, you're passing a varchar2 string `'an_aj_s.nextval'`. Oracle is expecting a number, not a string, so you get a ORA-01722 error.

You need to modify your function so that instead of this:

```
INSERT INTO AN_JOB (AJ_ID,AJ_JOBNAME,AJ_DESCRIPTION,AJ_CD_JOB_TYPE,AJ_CD_DATABASE,AJ_CD_JOB_STATUS,AJ_USR_ID,AJ_CREATE_DATE,AJ_EQUIP_COMPS_FLAG) 
VALUES ( :1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9 )
```

you're generating this:

```
INSERT INTO AN_JOB (AJ_ID,AJ_JOBNAME,AJ_DESCRIPTION,AJ_CD_JOB_TYPE,AJ_CD_DATABASE,AJ_CD_JOB_STATUS,AJ_USR_ID,AJ_CREATE_DATE,AJ_EQUIP_COMPS_FLAG) 
VALUES ( an_aj_s.nextval, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9 )
```

Does that make sense? There's a lot of ways you could change your function to do that, but you haven't explained your other use cases, so I don't want to suggest any particular one.

Alternately, you'll probably find it easier to do this on the Oracle side by creating a **sequence trigger**. There's a lot of examples on SO ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660307/creating-oracle-sequence-trigger))

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER an_job_id_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON an_job
FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (new.ID IS NULL)
BEGIN
  :new.ID := an_aj_s.nextval;
END;
/
```

That way, you can just leave out the `ID` column from your inserts altogether, and the trigger will handle it:

```
INSERT INTO AN_JOB (AJ_JOBNAME,AJ_DESCRIPTION,AJ_CD_JOB_TYPE,AJ_CD_DATABASE,AJ_CD_JOB_STATUS,AJ_USR_ID,AJ_CREATE_DATE,AJ_EQUIP_COMPS_FLAG) 
VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8 )
```

Comment: With Oracle DB 12 you can use a `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` clause when creating a table so you don't need an explicit sequence & trigger. E.g see [Creating a Table with an Identity Column: Examples](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CJAHCAFF).